# Using Angular 1 Directive in JavaScript in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angularjs-directive

I want to use an existing Angular 1 directive written in JavaScript which is part of a module in a new Angular 2 application.

All the information that I find online is related to an Angular 1 Component in TypeScript being used in Angular 2. I have tried this and it works.

But this is not what I want.

How can I make a simple JavaScript Directive written in Angular 1 to be used in Angular 2? I am not trying to migrate to Angular 2 but just use this Angular 1 directive as-is *with minimal code changes*.

Comment: You need to write new one. Please post your code so that someone can help you out.

Comment: Just posted the examples Angular 1 Directive in JavaScript

Comment: @digit please let me know if I can use this Javascript directive in Angular 2. If not, I am having a hard time understanding what is the use of ngUpgrade?